# How to do rewrite rule for PayPal IPN (htaccess)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers, paypal-ipn

Been at this for some hours now.

I need to redirect

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?option=com_acctexp&task=paypal_subscriptionnotification&Itemid=
```

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/dir/lib/ipn.php
```

So far I have tried all kind of combinations like these:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_acctexp&task=paypal_subscriptionnotification&Itemid=$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/lib/ipn.php [L]
```

[L] has also been replaced with [R=301,L] with little success

I am somewhat stumbling in the dark here as I do not know entirely what I am doing. I have read the Apache documentation but it is cryptic for me. I do not wish to keep the query string, however I would like to retain the json data sent with the ipn.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` at the end of your pattern means that it has to be an exact match - the querystring must end on the `=`, appending an `itemid` value will cause the match to fail. To pass the request through, you don't want to do a 301 redirect, that will result in a new request. To drop the querystring and prevent a loop, add a `?` to the end of your rewrite.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_acctexp&task=paypal_subscriptionnotification&Itemid=([^&]+?)
RewriteRule (.*) /dir/lib/ipn.php? [L]
```

Test on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
Input: http://www.example.com?option=com_acctexp&task=paypal_subscriptionnotification&Itemid=123

1  RewriteBase /    
2  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_acctexp&task=paypal_subscriptionnotification&Itemid=([^&]+?)
   This condition was met
3  RewriteRule (.*) /dir/lib/ipn.php? [L]
   This rule was met, the new url is http://www.example.com/dir/lib/ipn.php

   The tests are stopped because the L in your RewriteRule options

Output: http://www.example.com/dir/lib/ipn.php
```

Comment: "*The &*". You mean "The `$`"?